# searching strings in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple shopping cart. I need to allow for related products. My initial thought was to have a db field in the product table called tags which will have a comma delimited list of tags in it:

```
tag1,tag2,tag3
```

When I grab the product from the db I could also grab the tags and explode the string on the comma.

Problem is i'm having trouble thinking of a good way to then call to the db for all other products that have a matching tag. Is there way to search a string in SQL?

can anyone think of a good way to achieve this

Comment: when you set a field for tags then you need to use like operator and it will be very slow with large db, in my opinion you can use new table for tags with product id and tagname

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values. Read up on normalization.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - i would usually but products can have more than one related products tag no I'm not sure how to deal with that. It's not like I can store 1 tag id in the products table...I need to store an arbitrary number of tag id's - hence resorting to my current solution

Comment: Pleaso do *not* use any of the answers mentioning the `LIKE` syntax. For example `WHERE tags LIKE %tag1%` would match `tag1` but also `tag12` which is just wrong.

Comment: You would normalize such a situation by having a `products` table, a `tags` table and a `product_tags` table that defines the tags assigned to a product. This is a standard modelling pattern for a m:n relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not go down the route of storing comma separated strings in fields, its not very scalable (or [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)) . I would split this up into 3 different tables:

```
products:
-------------
id | name
-------------

1  | product 1
2  | product 2


tags:
---------------
id | tag
---------------

1  | tag 1
2  | tag 2


product_tags:
----------------------
product_id | tag_id
----------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
```

When you want to find products with related tags you would just do

```
    SELECT product_id FROM product_tags WHERE tag_id = TAG_ID
```

You could then use more advanced joining statements to return the records from the products table (instead of just product_id's from the tags table):

```
    SELECT products.* FROM products 
    INNER JOIN product_tags ON product_tags.product_id = products.id
    WHERE product_tags.tag_id = TAG_ID
```

Its a bit more work but it will save you headaches in the future.

Comment: Problem with this code is that I only have the product_id so your first query doesn't work because it's based on the tag_id.

Comment: In that case you would need to more than 1 query to achieve this. Could you not retrieve the tag_id and then do the query?

Comment: Yes, I could that's what I was thinking. Just doens't seem like a great solution. If a product had more than 1 tag for instance....

Comment: what about `SELECT 
products.*,
(
 SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(product_tags.tag_id)
 FROM product_tags
    WHERE product_tags.product_id = PUT_PRODUCT_ID_HERE
) as tags
FROM products
HAVING
FIND_IN_SET(products.id, tags) > 0` - this uses group_concat in a subquery to get the products tags, then uses find_in_set like @str example above

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` for that purpose:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE FIND_IN_SET('tag1', tags) > 0
```

However, I would strongly suggest to read on database normalization and joins instead.

Pleaso do *not* use any of the answers mentioning the `LIKE` syntax. For example `WHERE tags LIKE %tag1%` would match `tag1` but also `tag12` which is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To search for a string in SQL you can use the `LIKE` operator. Here is an example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value LIKE '%str%' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MySQL `LIKE` clause (check out this guide: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm). You may use it on each tag, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%tag1%' OR `tags` LIKE '%tag2%' OR `tags` lIKE '%tag3'
```